# How to fix Users & Groups / Other Users?

Tags: macos, user-account, high-sierra

I don't know how, but suddenly there are a lot of "Sharing Only" under Other Users. On my other mac, there are no such thing.

[image]

Directory Utility screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Never seen that! But all the users visible in your screenshot except yourself are "system users" = pre-defined users with special roles in the OS. Please add your system version!

Comment: I have macOS High Sierra 10.13.1 (17B48). Yes, that's very strange. 
Login screen (authorization after system boot) have all those other users as well, very annoying.

Comment: Can you take some screenshots of Directory Utility?

Comment: @JMY1000 added Directory Utility screenshots to post.

Comment: @Janiis I think it's either some hidden feature of the com.apple.loginwindow.plist (e.g. HiddenUsersList: *some array containing all system users*) or your DS db got wonky. Please add the output of `sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow`. You may have to redact some entries (e.g. lastUserName)!

Comment: @klanomath Here is output of the cmd. Does the output helps?

{
    GuestEnabled = 0;
    OptimizerLastRunForBuild = 35718656;
    OptimizerLastRunForSystem = 168624384;
    lastUser = loggedIn;
    lastUserName = janis;
    showInputMenu = 0;
}

Comment: @Janiis That's the default output & OK. So it's **not** some hidden feature of  com.apple.loginwindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating macOS High Sierra to version 10.13.2 (17C88) fixed the issue.